# Identify all the elements present in a page which are not visible but can be seen when scrolled down using c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There are 55 web elements present. On writing a common x path the fire bug shows only 37 matching elements and if you scroll down and again click on the "Eval button" the fire bug shows 43 matching elements.
I want to all all the 55 elements in a collection object so that i can click on all the elements one by one.

```
//div[img[contains(@class,'leaf')]]/span.
```

On identifying the elements with the above x path the code only clicks on 37 elements rather than clicking on 55 elements.

```
Ilist<IWebElement> elements=null;

elements=iDriver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//div[img[contains(@class,'leaf')]]/span."));
foreach(IWebElement option in elements)

{
  option.Click();
}
```

If I will be able to store those 55 elements in a collection then i will be able to click each and every element.
Is it possible to do it using the IJavaScriptExecutor.If yes what shall be the code??
Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the page loads dynamically that is as you scroll down the page loads. One way to achieve this would be first load the page by completing scrolling action using Actions class. Once the page has loaded then identify the elements. You should be able to identify all the elements. Happy coding.

Comment: @Vinay The page does not load dynamically, all the elements are loaded completely and completing the scrolling action does not help.

Comment: Is it a public page? Can you share the url?